# How to add a border to an image hidden in part?

Tags: css

This is my code ( if the image has an height higher than 100px then show only the first 100px of the image and hide the rest ):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    max-height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Now, I need to add a border of 5px:

```
img{
    border:solid 5px #555555;
}
```

but if the image has an height higher than 100px, the **bottom** border doesn't appear. How can I resolve that ?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the div's overflow is hidden. Instead, you should set the border on the div. This way, the div will only take up the height of the image but after 100px, it'll keep the border but the image won't show past that. You will need to adjust the width of the div to fit the image, though.

```
<span><img src="" /></span>

span{
    max-height:100px;
    border:solid 5px #555;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block
}

img {
    width: 200px; /* image width */
    height: 200px; /* image height */
}
```

Using a span with `display: inline-block` you no longer need to set the width of the outer container.

**Issue:** when image size is less than `100px`, there is a small gap between the image bottom and outer container.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kWJ8G/13/)

Comment: Yup, you are right. @xRobot should set the border of the `div` instead of the `img` since it is **clipped/hidden** and there is no way to make the bottom border visible when you forced it to be invisible in the first place.

Comment: then use `height` instead of `max-height`

Comment: @xRobot, why are you criticizing the answer's use of `max-height` when that merely came out of your question?

Comment: @DexterHuinda that's why I noted "You will need to adjust the width of the div to fit the image, though."

Comment: The above answer will not serve the purpose since the img's dimensions may vary e.g. width is < 200px. @xRobot wanted the border to wrap around the image, tight, no gaps.

Comment: yeah but that would defeat the purpose [i think], since like I said, the image dimensions vary, without notice. Am I right @xRobot? A display: inline-block does the trick of auto-adjusting the border width to fit snugly with the img width.

Comment: Also, there is a gap of about 5px right below the image and above the border, if the image height is < 100px, try adjusting your image height and you will see.

Comment: @DexterHuinda using a span you don't need to set the width (updated response). The small space is still troubling me.

Comment: @sachleen Yes, and if you use a `span`, you can't put margin's, padding's, or set dimensions.

Comment: Wasn't part of the question. We can't take into account everything that could possibly be done and make our solutions work for that. Each question is for something specific and the solutions should solve that problem. And actually, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek if this is what you need:

- (1st try) http://jsfiddle.net/Vn4PM/
- (last try) http://jsfiddle.net/Vn4PM/11/

HTML (with sample graphics):

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/100x150/ffff00/fff" />
</div>​
<div>
    <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/100x50/ffff00/fff" />
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    max-height: 100px;
    border: solid 5px #555555;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

img { margin-bottom: -5px; }​
```

--

- **display: inline-block**, and **border** added to div so border will *wrap* around the image
- **margin-bottom** added to img so extra gap is hidden

Comment: in this case if the image has an height of 50px then it show 2 bottom borders.

Comment: oh, that's right, so you really need to set the div's borders, not the img.

Comment: in the last case if the image has an height of 50px then it show a gap :D ( http://jsfiddle.net/Vn4PM/8/ )

Comment: @sachleen Right, which means there is no perfect solution for this problem. Btw, this is alpha version 0.000.001 so expect many bugs, lol.